# How can I fire a gun using SteamVR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I am attempting to make some sort of shooter game, and have a script that I am starting off with. It is a script to create a gun, and I can already pick it up and move it around because I attached a throwable script to the object. I am also able to fire it (I have a launch point and a projectile prefab). However, at the moment, the only way to fire it is with a button being pressed on the keyboard. I have a drop down menu and I can select which button I want to fire the gun. The problem is that I am attempting to make this a VR game, and so I need some way to fire the gun using my oculus touch controllers. I was wondering if there was a way to have buttons on your controller act like your pressing buttons on the keyboard, or if someone could tell me how I would modify my script so that I could use the steamVR Actions system.

I am using an oculus quest with oculus link, connected to steamVR, and Unity 2019.3.1 personal.

My Gun script is here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GenericGun : MonoBehaviour {
    public KeyCode fireKey = KeyCode.Mouse0;

    public GameObject projectilePrefab;
    public Transform launchPoint;
    public bool autoFire = false;
    [Tooltip("Projectile always fires along local Z+ direction of Launch Point")]
    public float launchVelocity;

    public float projectilesPerSecond = 1f;
    public float projectileLifetime = 3f;
    private float _lastFireTime = 0f;

    [Header("If checked, ignore all ammo settings below")]
    public bool infiniteAmmo = true;
    public int startingAmmo = 10;
    public int maxAmmo = 10;
    public int currentAmmo;
    public float ammoRechargeTime = 1f;
    private float _lastAmmoRechargeTime = 0f;


    void Start() {
        currentAmmo = startingAmmo;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (autoFire || Input.GetKey (fireKey))
        {
            Launch();
        }

        if (ammoRechargeTime > 0f && Time.time > _lastAmmoRechargeTime + ammoRechargeTime) {
            this.AddAmmo(1);
        }
    }

    public void Launch() {
        if (currentAmmo > 0f  && Time.time - _lastFireTime >= 1f / projectilesPerSecond)
        {
            _lastFireTime = Time.time;

            // ignore removing ammo if it's infinite
            if(!infiniteAmmo)
                currentAmmo -= 1;

            GameObject newGO;
            if (launchPoint != null)
            {
                newGO = GameObject.Instantiate (projectilePrefab, launchPoint.position, launchPoint.rotation) as GameObject;
            }
            else
            {
                newGO = GameObject.Instantiate (projectilePrefab, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            }

            Rigidbody newRB = newGO.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

            if (newRB != null)
            {
                newRB.AddRelativeForce (Vector3.forward * launchVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
            }
            if (projectileLifetime > 0f) {
                GameObject.Destroy(newGO, projectileLifetime);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddAmmo(int amount) {
        currentAmmo = Mathf.Min(maxAmmo, currentAmmo + 1);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

To generate inputs with Oculus Quest controllers you need to use `OVRInput`.

To do that you also need to include an instance of `OVRManager` in your scene, and call `OVRInput.Update()/FixedUpdate()` on the script you are handling the Input.

More information on the [docs](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-ovrinput/).

Comment: I am not trying to make a project for the oculus quest native, and I am not using the occulus SDK. I am attempting to make a project using steamVR, and so I need help with the SteamVR actions system.